# Is it correct to say "Rationality has taken over"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, sentence

For example, I want to say I used to be a heavy smoker but after going through the pros and cons of it, it had become evident to me it's time to quit, would it be grammatically correct to say:

- In the end, rationality has taken over and I gave up once and for good.

Implying that rationality has defeated the habit.

What's the more common way for expressing such thought?

Comment: It's reasonably grammatical and meaningful.  And exceedingly rare.

Comment: @HotLicks I've updated the question.

Comment: It's rare like "Peace has broken out." I think I remember peace. It was nice.

Comment: I would not say "once and for good".  I would say either "once and for all" or "for good".  These are both established idioms, but I would not mix them as you did.

Comment: The order is not quite right. Maybe rationality **took** over and I gave up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your question ***what is the common way?*** is more profound than it seems, and that it deserves a detailed answer.

The phrase ***rationality took over*** *could* be the best answer, it could be an indifferent answer, or it could be a bad answer and you definitely want to use something else. It *depends* on where you are, and what effect *you* want to achieve.

Questions of style are not like questions of grammar and vocabulary, which often have a right or wrong answer (though not always). Style like wearing color combinations: it's a matter of taste and propriety. Even if most people may like it one way (convention), some individuals may have a "personal style" that works perfectly well for them. And those individuals (if male) might still wear black wherever "dinner jacket" is required.

As @Cascabel correctly pointed out, "to take over" sounds a little unconventional. There is a precise reason: that's because "to take over" often has a *connotation* of acting forcefully, as in "the army took over". And opposing "force and reason" is quite commonplace in our culture. Hence putting force and reason side by side is a "clash of colors" that could be frowned upon.

*But* it could also be praised as an [oxymoron](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=oxymoron) (a figure of speech where you clash two things on purpose); as in *a deafening silence*, or (indeed) ***peace broke out*** (which I personally love). There is a whole litterary genre called [surrealism](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=surrealism) dedicated to practicing such incongruous juxtapositions.

So (in the extreme) the *common way* if you were a surrealist might indeed be to write ***rationality took over***.

Now, if you want to use the *common way* in educated circles such as universities or the management of international corporations etc., you might want to write

> ***Rationality prevailed* and I gave up once and for all**

(and that might indeed be what you are looking for?). That's because [*to prevail*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=prevail) has a connotation of persuasion that goes well with rationality. Furthermore, *prevail* is quite dignified, and invites support from well-to-do people who dislike the excesses of common folk.

Indeed, would it be *common* , if you went to a shop, to hear a patron casually saying *rationality prevailed*? Unless it was some upscale boutique in London or New York, I wouldn't think so.

As @Cascabel wisely pointed out, you'd rather hear:

> ***I came to my senses* and gave it up for good**.

Then the little details, such as using *gave it up*, rather than *gave up* are quirks that depend on the location, and who is talking, etc. If you really want to nail it (as when you are starting in a new city or on a new job) I'm afraid the only solution is to collect **samples** of what people are actually writing, or to listen carefully to what they are actually saying.

Answer (score 2):

***come to one's  senses***

> to begin to think in a sensible or correct way after being foolish or wrong

[MerriamWebster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20to%20one%27s%20senses)

> **In the end, I *came to my senses* and gave it up for good. // once and for all**.

Please note that "once and for all", and "for good" are different idioms.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it's perfectly okay if you take away the 'has taken over' and replace it with 'took over'. Or even 'had taken over' would be fine.